# How to add seekbar to Exoplayer exo_playback_control_view.xml

Tags: android, android-seekbar, exoplayer

cannot add seekbar to explayer

Ia ma referring to 
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a

to add custom play pause button and seekbar to exoplayer

this is the code I am trying

```
public class ExoplayerAct extends Activity implements VideoRendererEventListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private TextView resolutionTextView;
    String j;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exoplayer);
        resolutionTextView = new TextView(this);
        resolutionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resolution_textView);

        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            j = (String) b.get("fileVideoPath");
        }

// 1. Create a default TrackSelector
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

// 2. Create a default LoadControl
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

// 3. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

//Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);

        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();


// Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);


// I. ADJUST HERE:
//CHOOSE CONTENT: LiveStream / SdCard

//LIVE STREAM SOURCE: * Livestream links may be out of date so find any m3u8 files online and replace:

//        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://81.7.13.162/hls/ss1/index.m3u8"); //random 720p source
//        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://54.255.155.24:1935//Live/_definst_/amlst:sweetbcha1novD235L240P/playlist.m3u8"); //Radnom 540p indian channel
//        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("FIND A WORKING LINK ABD PLUg INTO HERE"); //PLUG INTO HERE<------------------------------------------


//VIDEO FROM SD CARD: (2 steps. set up file and path, then change videoSource to get the file)
//        String urimp4 = "path/FileName.mp4"; //upload file to device and add path/name.mp4
//         Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/2010a.mp4");

        Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(j);





//Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
//Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this
                , Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);
//Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();


// II. ADJUST HERE:

//This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played:
//FOR SD CARD SOURCE:
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

//FOR LIVESTREAM LINK:
//        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);

// Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(loopingSource);

        player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onTimelineChanged...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onTracksChanged...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:"+isLoading);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerStateChanged..." + playbackState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onRepeatModeChanged...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerError...");
                player.stop();
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPositionDiscontinuity...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlaybackParametersChanged...");
            }
        });
        PlaybackParameters playbackParameters = new PlaybackParameters(2.0f, 1.0f);
        player.setPlaybackParameters(playbackParameters);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
        player.setVideoDebugListener(this); //for listening to resolution change and  outputing the resolution
    }//End of onCreate

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged ["  + " width: " + width + " height: " + height + "]");
        resolutionTextView.setText("RES:(WxH):"+width+"X"+height +"\n           "+height+"p");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }




//-------------------------------------------------------ANDROID LIFECYCLE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStop()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStart()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "onPause()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()...");
        player.release();
    }
}
```

the exoplayer layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
    tools:context="com.ayalus.exoplayer2example.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_app_title"
        android:text="ExoPlayer 2 Example App:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resolution_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resolution"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sample_app_title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resolution_textView"
        app:use_controller="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

and the custom exo_playback_control_view

is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <!--<SeekBar android:id="@id/exo_progress"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="32dp"-->
            <!--android:focusable="false"-->
            <!--style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>-->

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I comment the seekbar as above , it works correctly

but If I add the seekbar it gives me error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SeekBar cannot be cast to com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TimeBar
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your exo_playback_control_view layout replace `Seekbar` with `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar`

This is what the error message is telling you, and if you check the docs [here](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.html) you'll find that the type given for the exo_progress control is indeed TimeBar.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
    android:id="@id/exo_progress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="26dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by creating a layout named: exo_player_control_view.xml and override the regular XML.

On this one below is the standard XML, You can add `android:visiblite="invisible"` for `DefaultTimeBar` which is what I think you're trying to hide, if not feel free change it as you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_repeat_toggle"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```